# Ruby Heapify Implementation / Optimization

Tags: ruby, algorithm, recursion, tree, heap

I'm implementing a Heapify algorithm in Ruby (that is, converting a binary tree into a heap), and think the below works. My concern is I'm making too many recursive calls.

First and second recursive call is to pick the highest node from left and right subtrees, third recursive call is for doing the same when I swap nodes. Haven't included my swap_parent_child method, a bit long but it works.

```
def max_heapify(node)
  return nil if node.nil?
  return node if node.left.nil? && node.right.nil?

  left = max_heapify(node.left)
  right = max_heapify(node.right)

  max_value = find_max_value(node, left, right)

  if node.value == max_value
    node
  elsif left && left.value == max_value
    swap_parent_child(node, left)
    max_heapify(node)
    left
  else
    swap_parent_child(node, right)
    max_heapify(node)
    right
  end
end

def find_max_value(node, node2, node3)
  max_value = node.value
  max_value = node2.value if node2 && node2.value > max_value
  max_value = node3.value if node3 && node3.value > max_value

  max_value
end
```

I've checked the algorithm listed here, but I'm not convinced it works. https://www.cs.rit.edu/~rpj/courses/bic2/studios/studio1/studio121.html#M502

Seems like the algo according to that site would do the following and stop.

```
5              5
|\             | \
2 4      =>    10 4
|              |
10             2
```

What am I missing here? Or does heapifying a tree really need three recursive calls per method call?

Comment: If memory serves, the first step of the heapsort algorithm is sometimes referred to as "heapify". Is that correct?

Comment: Hmm not sure Cary, but seems that's true from Wikipedia. I'm just trying to convert a binary tree into a heap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone stumbling on this in the future, the right approach is to heapify an array representing a tree, rather than an actual binary tree with parent and left & right pointers.

This section on Wikipedia really helped me: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap#Heap_implementation